# Is there a plugin or something that allows you to use BuddyPress without having to create a BuddyPress-ready theme?

Tags: buddypress

It's an inconvenience to have to customize your theme just to use BuddyPress.

It'd be much nicer if it simply used the wordpress page system for example, to inject content into standard WP pages. This way no theme editing is necessary, just activate BP and go.

The idea would be that BuddyPress would just work in TwentyTen with off the shelf wordpress install + BuddyPress.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a plugin for that (bptemplate pack). It works pretty well! http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bp-template-pack/

Comment: Sweeeeet. Looks cool! It says it's for version 2.9.1 of WP though. Will have to test it out with WP3.1 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! Starting with version 1.7, [BuddyPress should work with most themes out of the box](http://codex.buddypress.org/theme-compatibility/). You can work with their stock template or you can pick and choose the parts you want to customize:

> BuddyPress 1.7 has built-in theme support. All required elements such as front-end editing are included. This means that all functionality will work, even when a theme has no specific BuddyPress templates or code included with it.
>
> All BuddyPress compat can be overridden using a theme or another plugin. Check bp-theme-compat template wrappers for what a normal theme should include.
>
> **To customize BuddyPress:**
>
> The directory `wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-templates/bp-legacy/` contains the directories `buddypress`, `css` and `js`, and the file `buddypress-functions.php`.
>
> - `buddypress` contains template files; copy any you want to modify into a directory named `buddypress` in your theme’s root. eg. `/wp-content/mytheme/buddypress/`
> - `css` contains style sheets; copy any you want to modify into a directory named `css` in your theme’s root. eg. `/wp-content/mytheme/css/`
>
> Edit the new files for complete control over BuddyPress display in your theme.